# I am working in pycharm and using pandas. I wanted to write groupby values to the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Code-

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\abc\Downloads\data1.csv')
for c,b in d:
 print(c)
 print(b)
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\abc\Downloads\date.csv')
```

console output that i want to write in csv file

```
Austria
      Brand Market  ... Audible Viewable Measured Impressions
81         Austria  ...                                   653
133        Austria  ...                                     0
134        Austria  ...                                     1
144        Austria  ...                                     0
302        Austria  ...                                     0
...            ...  ...                                   ...
61153      Austria  ...                                     2
61248      Austria  ...                                     0
61298      Austria  ...                                    39
61798      Austria  ...                                    14
61990      Austria  ...                                     0

[723 rows x 29 columns]
Belgium
      Brand Market  ... Audible Viewable Measured Impressions
34         Belgium  ...                                     8
35         Belgium  ...                                     9
63         Belgium  ...                                     1
65         Belgium  ...                                     0
108        Belgium  ...                                    32
```

Comment: you haven't defined `d`, you should put the `to_csv` in the loop (with a variable file name)

Comment: By the way, your paths are not proper: all backslashes should be double: \\ , or use raw strings: r”C:\something\something\file.csv”